# Pi-Pico /dev/ttyACM0 (USB serial) disappearing -- I2C testing with C

Tags: pi-pico

[ Pi-4B 8GB ] <-USB->[ Pi-Pico ]

I have the USB serial enabled in the CMakeLists.txt file:
pico_enable_stdio_uart(i2c_test_01 0)
pico_enable_stdio_usb(i2c_test_01 1)
yet I find there is no /dev/ttyACM0.

It seems the USB serial device goes away and later (may) return.
Any ideas/suggestions on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help.  As a minimum you need to show the code you are using.

Comment: [SOLVED] The /dev/ttyACM0 USB serial device is created after the cmake/make/UF2 copy
processes are complete.

Comment: Why not make that an answer?